# How do you call a web service in Java with only XSD and NO WSDL?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, cxf, jaxb2

I have a web service outside of my company that provides no WSDL for their service.  They **do** provide:

- a detailed document on how to `POST` to their service
- what a `SoapEnvelope` should look like
- and even an `.xsd` that I can use to create the message to put in the SOAP `<env:Body></env:Body>` of the call.

**How do you make a SOAP call to a web service without a WSDL (in Java)?**  I need a tool that can take my JAXB-formatted XML message, wrap it in a SOAP Envelope, and send it as HTTP POST to some web service (with SSL and Certificates).

Are there tools that make this easy?  I've looked at [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) with [JAX-WS dispatch](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-dispatch-api.html) briefly, but since most examples and documentation expect a `wsdl` document, I am not sure if CXF is what I should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did they give you the URL? Try to surf to http://the-url-of-service-that-does-not-provide-wsdl/**wsdl**

this is the standard URL where you should download the WSDL file (unless they coded everything by hand).

OK, if not you have 2 ways

1. Create the WSDL yourself based on their document.
2. Parse the SOAP XML using any tool you know. For example JAXB, Digester, DOM

Comment: They provide me a long-winded pdf that explains how to formulate a request, what all coulpe hundred request types are, and an XSD to throw into the <body></body> of your SOAP call, but they state: "Although SOAP is a recognized Web Services API, the RTO web server does not offer a web services interface. That is, there is no Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file available for usage by
participant web services client software."

Comment: I think if you have the XSD that defines your soap messages, and a document that defines which schema elements can/should be populated in each soap request, then you can certainly build yourself a WSDL that conforms to that specification. building a wsdl yourself and using built in code generation provided by JAX-WS (or whatever tool you like for soap services) is much nicer than writing the code by hand. if you think you would like to try this out and need some help, let me know.